# nginx and proxy_redirect partially working?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, nginx, proxy

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to reverse proxy a .NET application (specifically sharepoint)

- The sharepoint application lives at 192.168.5.8
- nginx lives at 192.168.2.115 and has another IP at 192.168.5.200
- I am using nginx to proxy several applications using the url to distinguish each app

My problem is with "/vmlab/" and not "/rdp/"

**sites-available/default**:

```
 location ^~ /vmlab {
            proxy_pass              http://192.168.5.8/;
            proxy_redirect          http://192.168.2.115/   http://192.168.2.115/vmlab/;
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            client_max_body_size    10m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
            proxy_connect_timeout   90;
            proxy_send_timeout      90;
            proxy_read_timeout      90;
            proxy_buffers           32 4k;
            proxy_set_header        Authorization "Basic {base64 string}";
    }

 location /rdp/ {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.2.115:8080;
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            client_max_body_size    10m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
            proxy_connect_timeout   90;
            proxy_send_timeout      90;
            proxy_read_timeout      90;
            proxy_buffering         off;
            #proxy_buffers           32 4k;
    }
```

So when I hit `http://192.168.2.115/vmlab` the back-end request goes to `http://192.168.5.8` which is great, except that the web application automatically sends a location redirect `Location: http://192.168.2.115/default.aspx`, therefore I added the `proxy_redirect` which seems to partially work.

My problem is that even though some requests like `http://192.168.2.115/vmlab/default.aspx` are being now being proxied to `http://192.168.5.8/default.aspx` (but show as `http://192.168.2.115/vmlab/default.aspx`) with the proxy_redirect, others that show up in the client browser (such as javascripts and stylesheets) still show like the following `http://192.168.2.115/`**_layouts**`/...` which is missing the required **"/vmlab/"** URI and therefore don't exist.

Is this a problem with my configuration and the proxy, or by design with absolute paths in stylesheets and javascript code?

Comment: you need to add location block in nginx config file for those static files.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just creating a different virtual host for "sites-available" and created the location block from the root URI so that everything can be proxied